# C++ zip variadic templates

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

Here is a simple two-container zip function in C++:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::list<std::pair<A, B> > simple_zip(const std::list<A> & lhs,
                                       const std::list<B> & rhs)
{
  std::list<std::pair<A, B> >  result;
  for (std::pair<typename std::list<A>::const_iterator,
                 typename std::list<B>::const_iterator> iter
       =
       std::pair<typename std::list<A>::const_iterator,
                 typename std::list<B>::const_iterator>(lhs.cbegin(),
                                                        rhs.cbegin());
       iter.first != lhs.end() && iter.second != rhs.end();
       ++iter.first, ++iter.second)
  {
    result.push_back( std::pair<A, B>(*iter.first, *iter.second) );
  }
  return result;
}
```

How would I extend this to an arbitrary number of containers with variadic templates?

I'd like `general_zip` to accept a `tuple` of `list`s (each list can contain a different type) and return a `list` of `tuple`s.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631782/implementing-a-variadic-zip-function-with-const-correctness

Comment: That amazingly-long-for-initialization-statement could be rewritten as `auto iter = std::make_pair(lhs.cbegin(), rhs.cbegin())`. Your declaration is waaaaay to long.

Comment: @dirkgently I've seen that question, but it's a bit of a mess and doesn't seem to have a successful conclusion... any others that you'd recommend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like this should work

```
std::list<std::tuple<>> simple_zip() {
  return {};
}

template <typename ...T>
std::list<std::tuple<T...>> simple_zip(std::list<T>... lst)
{
  std::list<std::tuple<T...>>  result;
  for (int i = 0, e = std::min({lst.size()...}); i != e; i++) {
    result.emplace_back(std::move(lst.front())...);
    [](...){} ((lst.pop_front(), 0)...);
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

@Potatoswatter had the good (IMO) remark that this may copy more than needed when the lists are of different size, and that using only iterators will be better since pop_front does more than actually needed. I think the following "fixes" the iterator one at the cost of more code.

```
template <typename ...T>
std::list<std::tuple<T...>> simple_zip(std::list<T>... lst)
{
  std::list<std::tuple<T...>>  result;
  struct {
    void operator()(std::list<std::tuple<T...>> &t, int c,
             typename std::list<T>::iterator ...it) {
      if(c == 0) return;
      t.emplace_back(std::move(*it++)...);
      (*this)(t, c-1, it...);
    }
  } zip;
  zip(result, std::min({lst.size()...}), lst.begin()...);
  return result;
}

std::list<std::tuple<>> simple_zip() {
  return {};
}
```

Comment: I assume that the  `struct { int dummy; } pops[] = { (lst.pop_front(), 0)... };` is to force the parameter unpack?  Overall, very interesting solution.  +1

Comment: +1 Wow, this is incredibly elegant! I am so impressed and grateful.

One small change: I got a compiler error for `std::min(lst.size()...)`; `std::min(1,2,3)` doesn't work for me, but `std::min({1,2,3})` does, so I added the curly braces.

Comment: `struct { int dummy; } pops[] = { (lst.pop_front(), 0)... };` Clever abuse, I'll have to remember this.

Comment: Couldn't the anonymous struct be a `std::initializer_list` instead, which would be deduced from `auto`: `auto pops = { (lst.pop_front(), 0)... };`

Comment: @Potatoswatter sure. it could also be an `alias<int[]>{ (lst.pop_front(), 0)... }` with a proper identity alias template. Or `[](...){}((lst.pop_front(), 0)...);` (in this one the order of the poppings is unspecified). There are lots of possibilities :)

Comment: The most generic would be an expansion that allows arbitrary statements, which both of GCC and clang don't support yet, though: `alias<int[]>{([]{ lst.pop_front(); }(),0)...}`.

Comment: The initlist thing has the drawback that you need to include the initializer_list header :( The alias template has the drawback that you need to define an alias template somewhere first (or put a "typedef int expander[];" which I guess isn't anymore ugly than what I have currently with the anonymous struct though). The lambda thing  is really perverted xD

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Wait a minute, you passed the lists by value, because this is a value-semantic function. You're popping empty items from a bunch of containers that are about to get destroyed anyway. I'ma write my own…

Comment: @Potatoswatter I don't understand what your last comment should imply. Is my function inefficient and for what reason? What's an "empty item" in this context?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I think I had a bug with "pops[] = { ... }" for the case where no lists are passed and one would expect a "std::list<std::tuple<>>();" as the return. I believe that is fixed now. Now that I also fixed the max(...) bug to use an init list I guess one could just as well use your expand trick since one needs to include <initializer_list> anyway :)

Comment: Bah the "std::min({0, ....})" was stupid :) Can't see a way without having the additional overload there.

Comment: Is it just me or does `[](...){}` look like a robot who is sad and bored because all he can do is no-op?

Comment: Well… I've spent a long time on this now, and succeeded in nothing except crashing GCC 4.7.0 before it could produce any diagnostic output. Kudos to you!!

Comment: @Potatoswatter unfortunately if we accept `std::list<T> &&list` it will no more accept lvalues (no "special deduction" takes place). So it would need to accept "T &&t" and assert with SFINAE or something that all of them are std::lists. way ugly.

Comment: @ildjarn beware that it has the hidden pitfall that it fails for a pack expansion with 0 elements :( That's why I replaced it above

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb huh? What did I say about rvalues? Oh, it turns out GCC was keeping some sort of internal state, now it accepted my program with no changes :vP . I'll just write it up now.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i mean if we still want to move the elements out of the list but don't want to copy/move *all* elements (if they have non-equal size), is becomes even more boilerplate :(

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb to absolutely minimize copies, all you need is to add a few `const`, pass by reference, and remove `move`: http://ideone.com/HoS1G

Comment: @Potatoswatter huh? if you pass rvalue lists then that code copies all elements instead of moving it. My code copies and moves lvalues once and moves rvalues twice. So that code has one copy more than my version.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb oh, I see. Here's a solution that moves rvalues, without too much boilerplate, although it's a bit bigger and a lot uglier. There are plenty of ways to express it but it took a while to find one that didn't ICE G++. http://ideone.com/RfxMg

Answer (score 4):

This is an incremental improvement on Johannes' first answer. It avoids the dummy `struct` and avoids copying the entire input lists (although this doesn't matter much unless one list is shorter than the others). Also I made it generic over all containers.

But it requires a boilerplate pack-index generator, which is quite useful anyway

```
template< std::size_t n, typename ... acc >
struct make_index_tuple {
    typedef typename make_index_tuple<
        n - 1,
        std::integral_constant< std::size_t, n - 1 >, acc ...
    >::type type;
};

template< typename ... acc >
struct make_index_tuple< 0, acc ... >
    { typedef std::tuple< acc ... > type; };
```

The "real" implementation consists of a straightforward function which requires the output from the above utility, and an interface function which maps packs to tuples.

```
template< typename ret_t, std::size_t ... indexes, typename lst_tuple >
ret_t simple_zip( std::tuple< std::integral_constant< std::size_t, indexes > ... >,
    lst_tuple const &lst ) {
    ret_t ret;

    auto iters = std::make_tuple( std::get< indexes >( lst ).begin() ... );
    auto ends = std::make_tuple( std::get< indexes >( lst ).end() ... );

    while ( std::max< bool >({ std::get< indexes >( iters )
                            == std::get< indexes >( ends ) ... }) == false ) {
        ret.emplace_back( * std::get< indexes >( iters ) ++ ... );
    }
    return ret;
}

template< typename ... T >
std::list< std::tuple< typename T::value_type ... > >
simple_zip( T const & ... lst ) {
    return simple_zip
        < std::list< std::tuple< typename T::value_type ... > > > (
        typename make_index_tuple< sizeof ... lst >::type(),
        std::tie( lst ... )
    );
}
```

At the least, this puts into perspective what Johannes made look easy. This is what most variadic template algorithms look like, because there is no way to store type-variadic state without `tuple`, and there is no way to process a variadic tuple without a pack of indexes or a meta-recursive function. (Edit: ah, now Johannes used a tail-recursive local function to define local packs to do all that with no `tuple` at all. Awesome… if you can handle all the functional programming ;v) .)

Comment: Good code. " std::max< bool > ({ std::get< indexes >( iters )== std::get< indexes >( ends ) ... }) == false" HAHA that's clever.

Answer (score 2):

Another version : a mix of Johannes and Potatoswatter answer, trying to minimize the amount of trickery (which I enjoyed nevertheless !)

```
template <typename C, typename... Its>
void simple_zip_details(C& c, size_t size, Its... its)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      c.emplace_back(std::move(*its++)...);
}

template <typename... Ts>
std::list<std::tuple<Ts...>> simple_zip(std::list<Ts>... lst)
{
   std::list<std::tuple<Ts...>>  result;
   size_t size = std::min({ lst.size()... });
   simple_zip_details(result, size, lst.begin()...);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: With the disclaimer that I haven't tested it (I assume you did), I am very impressed with the brevity of your code.