# C++11 variadic templates: return tuple from variable list of vectors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to write something similar to python zip (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).
zip should take in a variable number of vectors of different types and it returns a vector
of tuples, truncated to the length of the shortest input.

E.g.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
v = ['a', 'b']
```

I want the output to be a vector of
`[ <1, 'a'>, <2, 'b'>]`

How do I do this in C++11?

Comment: In your example shouldn't the vectors be the same length

Comment: @aaronman no, he states truncation to shortest

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631782/implementing-a-variadic-zip-function-with-const-correctness) almost exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I think tuple_cat would do the trick

Comment: @duli In the spirit of the `<algorithm>` header, I've written an answer that operates on general ranges (as opposed to just `vector`).

Comment: Returning a generator would have been more pythonic.

Comment: @Xeo Come on, I had real fun doing it a while ago.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Doing this eagerly and only with copying is pretty easy:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

template<class... Ts>
std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> zip(std::vector<Ts> const&... vs){
    auto lo = std::min({vs.size()...});
    std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> v;
    v.reserve(lo);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < lo; ++i)
        v.emplace_back(vs[i]...);
    return v;
}
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/wyVCwj)

With perfect forwarding and allowing moves out of the vector, it becomes just a bit more complicated, mostly due to the helpers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
using Invoke = typename T::type;

template<class T>
using Unqualified = Invoke<std::remove_cv<Invoke<std::remove_reference<T>>>>;

template<class T>
using ValueType = typename Unqualified<T>::value_type;

template<class T>
T const& forward_index(std::vector<T> const& v, unsigned i){
    return v[i];
}

template<class T>
T&& forward_index(std::vector<T>&& v, unsigned i){
    return std::move(v[i]);
}

template<class... Vs>
std::vector<std::tuple<ValueType<Vs>...>> zip(Vs&&... vs){
    auto lo = std::min({vs.size()...});
    std::vector<std::tuple<ValueType<Vs>...>> v;
    v.reserve(lo);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < lo; ++i)
        v.emplace_back(forward_index(std::forward<Vs>(vs), i)...);
    return v;
}
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/tnVX2r)

Comment: I might edit this to be fully generic tomorrow, but it's going to be a bit more complex then (being able to use just a single counter for all containers is really nice).

Comment: I was wondering about the usage of move semantics. It looks like the second template function `forward_index` is never used, because `vs` is a lvalue reference. I think it should be changed to `forward_index(std::forward<Vs>(vs), i)...`?

Comment: @nosid: Erm... yes. I originally passed the vector type explicitly, but that disappeared during refactoring. Thanks.

Comment: I think you could also use `std::decay` instead of the double remove. Should do the same, but is more direct and streamlined.

Comment: @ChristianRau: It doesn't do exactly the same - namely, it also *decays* certain types - function types to function pointers, arrays to pointers, etc. And it conveys the wrong semantics.

Comment: @Xeo But you code already requires the argument of `ValueType` to be a vector, so functions and arrays are not an option at all. Ok, the semantics are arguable, I have come accustomed to see `decay` used instead of double remove (and I hate the latter so much), but you're right in that it is rather for function argument decay.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, that may be so, but it still conveys the wrong semantics - I just want the raw, *unqualified* type. Also, consistency - if I use `Decay` in some situations, and `Unqualified` in others.. nah, let's not go there.

Comment: @Xeo Well Ok, `Unqualified` is nice and better than everything else, but I wouldn't have made that helper anyway (and not only because as a VS lover I can't) and I just hate that double `typename` rubbish. But I agree that `std::decay` might convey the wrong semantics when seen from certain viewpoints.

Comment: Meh eager :P that's cheating

Answer (score 5):

The following template function may be a good starting point.

```
template <typename ...Types>
auto zip(const std::vector<Types>&... values)
    -> std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>>
{
    auto size = std::min({ values.size()... });
    std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>> result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        result.emplace_back(values[i]...);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I like how we both have `std::min({ vecs.size()... })` and iterate up to there.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want. It works for any range as opposed to just `vector`.

```
template <typename Iterator0, typename Iterator1>
std::vector<std::tuple<
    typename Iterator0::value_type,
    typename Iterator1::value_type>>
zip(
    Iterator0 begin0, Iterator0 end0,
    Iterator1 begin1, Iterator1 end1)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<
        typename Iterator0::value_type,
        typename Iterator1::value_type>> result;
    while (begin0 != end0 && begin1 != end1)
    {
        result.emplace_back(*begin0, *begin1);
        ++begin0;
        ++begin1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You call it like this.

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<double> y;
auto xy = zip(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());
```

You can [**try it out here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=53b0e18583a29aa7397586cc61830d18-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Is is probably possible to modify `zip` to use variadic templates, so that you can zip any number of ranges together.

To further match the `<algorithm>` header, you could return `void` and instead take an output iterator to which the output will be written.

Comment: Algorithm,  while groundbreaking at the time, does not reflect current best C++11practices .

Comment: @Yakk Supporting general ranges as opposed to just `vector`s isn't best practice?

Comment: Support general containers (or iterable objects), not ranges, so caller does not have to repeat herself: an iterable object is one for which `for(auto&& x: obj)` works.  The above is not bad, just we can do better now!  As an aside, your algorithm fails to work on `int*`, which are iterators, extending the above to variardic is a pain, does not exploit `-` on random access iterators and `reserve` to halve memory allocation overhead (good generic code should be as fast as custom code), and taking an output iterator makes many optimizations impossible.

Comment: You could at least use `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` to make it more generic (and work for things like pointers).